# Handling misstyped file references in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am using "Mastering Ext JS 4" book to learn Ext JS 4. All in all it is going well and I found solutions to most of the problems. My question is, how to prevent errors with using mistyped names of models/view/controllers.

For example here is my controller

```
Ext.define('MyAppName.controller.MyController', {
     extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

     requires:[
        'Packt.util.MD5',
        'Packt.util.Util',
        'Packt.util.SessionMonitor'
     ],

     init: function(){
         // controller stuff here
     }
});
```

It uses file called MD5.js which is located in my application "app" folder and in subfolder called util.

While building my test application I managed to mistype name of views, models stores and then I had to search for the error in files.

For example what if I missed to write one letter like this:

```
 requires:[
    'Pack.util.MD5',
    'Packt.util.Util',
    'Packt.util.SessionMonitor'
],
```

Firebug will notify my about missing file located in application folder called 'Pack' which doesn't exist.

Should I create a separate js file where I will give short names to the strings 'Packt.util.MD5', 'Packt.util.Util', 'Packt.util.SessionMonitor' for easier access?

Or is there some more neat ExtJS 4 method to solve this issue and prevent mistype errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no automation would save you from all typos, unfortunately. But for shorter names you can give your classes [alternateClassName](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-alternateClassName). For example, `Packt.util.MD5` can have alternate class name `Packt.MD5`.

Comment: So I set alternateClassName: 'MD5'. This will work: requres:['MD5'] ?

Comment: I wouldn't go to the global space, I'd still wrap everything in the root namespace `Packt`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to avoid mistype error is to use editors with itellisense. you will find both paid and free versions for them .You can also make a habit to give sensible names .
Please refer to the link which might help u.[editors](http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-69532.html)